# Como quito los errores unary operator expected

Tags: bash, script

Estoy intentando quitar los errores unary operator expected de mi script pero no soy capaz

Mi codigo es este

```
#!/bin/bash

Notamax=0
Notamin=10

while IFS=";" read alumne nota
do
    if [ $nota -gt $Notamax ]; then    
        Notamax=$nota
    fi
    
    if [ $nota -lt $Notamin ]; then
        Notamin=$nota
    fi

done <"/home/admin/scripts/notas.txt"
echo "Nota maxima $Notamax ** Alumnos con nota maxima:"
while IFS=";" read alumne nota
do
    if [ $nota -eq $Notamax ]; then
       echo "$alumne, $Notamax"
    fi
echo "Nota minima $Notamin ** Alumnos con nota minima:"
while IFS=";" read alumne nota
do
    if [ $nota -eq $Notamin ]; then
        echo "$alumne, $Notamin"
    fi

done <"/home/admin/scripts/notas.txt"
```

El problema esta en que todos los -gt -lt -eq me dan el error unary, he probado a poner todos con doble corchete tipo [[ $nota -eq $notamin ]]
Pero aunque el error se quita no se por que la variable $notamin me da un valor incorrecto.

**Hay otra forma de quitar ese error que no sea los dobles corchetes?**

Comment: Se me olvido comentar que el fichero de donde el script recoge las notas es un fichero simple con nombre y nota

pepe;5
marcos:7

De este estilo, pero no creo que el error venga de ese fichero

Comment: `-eq` es usado en comparaciones de valores numéricos. Al leer el valor del fichero, este será tratado como cadena de texto.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no me da el error que comentas.

Pero es que además de eso, no entiendo por qué recorres el contenido del archivo varias veces ¿?

Si se trata de obtener el valor máximo y mínimo, puedes hacerlo simplemente con algo como esto:

```
(( nota > Notamax )) && Notamax=$nota alumneMax=$alumne
(( nota < Notamin || Notamin == 0)) && Notamin=$nota alumneMin=$alumne
```

Ejemplo completo:

#### `notas.txt`

```
pepe;5
marcos;7
marta;70
julio;1
```

#### Código:

```
#!/bin/sh
Notamax=0
Notamin=0
alumneMax=''
alumneMin=''
while IFS=";" read alumne nota
do
    (( nota > Notamax )) && Notamax=$nota alumneMax=$alumne
    (( nota < Notamin || Notamin == 0)) && Notamin=$nota alumneMin=$alumne

done <notas.txt
echo "Nota maxima $Notamax ** Alumnos con nota maxima: $alumneMax"
echo "Nota minima $Notamin ** Alumnos con nota minima: $alumneMin"
```

**Salida:**

```
Nota maxima 70 ** Alumnos con nota maxima: marta
Nota minima 1 ** Alumnos con nota minima: julio
```

Si de todos modos quieres hacerlo con un `if`, entonces sería:

```
#!/bin/sh
Notamax=0
Notamin=0
alumneMax=''
alumneMin=''
while IFS=";" read alumne nota
do
    if (( nota > Notamax )); then
        Notamax=$nota
        alumneMax=$alumne
    fi

    if (( (nota < Notamin)  || (Notamin == 0) )); then
        Notamin=$nota
        alumneMin=$alumne
    fi
done <notas.txt
echo "Nota maxima $Notamax ** Alumnos con nota maxima: $alumneMax"
echo "Nota minima $Notamin ** Alumnos con nota minima: $alumneMin"
```

La salida será la misma.

Comment: Gracias Cedano tu respuesta me ayudo a mejorar el script, aunque a lo de por que recorro el fichero varias veces fue la única manera que se me ocurrió de hacer que en el caso de que 2 personas tengan la misma nota me muestre las 2 y no solo 1 como en tu solución, si conoces otra manera mas optima me gustaría conocerla :)

Answer (score 0):

Si se trata de agrupar todos los alumnos que tienen la mayor y la menor nota, puedes hacer algo parecido a esto usando `awk` ([ver este tutorial introductorio sobre `awk`](http://www.linuxfocus.org/Castellano/September1999/article103.html)):

```
awk -F ';' 'NR==1 { min = max = $2; mina = maxa = $1; next }
  { val = "," $1 }
  $2==max { maxa = maxa val }
  $2==min { mina = mina val }
  $2>max { max = $2; maxa = $1 }
  $2<min { min = $2; mina = $1 }
  END { printf "Max: %2i [%s]\n", max, maxa
    printf "Min: %2i [%s]\n", min, mina }' notas.txt
```

Si en `notas.txt` hubiera esto:

```
pepe;5
marcos;7
marta;70
luis;70
ana;5
pedro;9
paco;70
pepa;7
rosa;5
manu;8
```

La salida sería:

```
Max: 70 [marta,luis,paco]
Min:  5 [pepe,ana,rosa]
```

---

**Fuente:** Ver respuestas a [esta pregunta en Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76248531/5587982).